# How Do I Change The Order That In-App Purchase Products Display?

Tags: in-app-purchase, app-store-connect, testflight

I'm trying to test our app with an auto-renewable subscription (in app purchase) in Testflight, but the subscription tiers (products) aren't in the correct order.

When I run the build from xcode on device, the products show in the display order that I want:

Free 
All Features Monthly ($) 
All Features Annually ($$)

However when I upload to app store connect, then install that build using Testflight on my device, the order shows differently:

Free (read only) 
All Features Annually ($$) 
All Features Monthly ($)

How/where is the order determined so that I can change it? 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lASW1.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tCNJi.png)